# Ruby error message is hidden in jekyll output

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress, jekyll-bootstrap

When I run command `jekyll build` and have some ruby error, the first few lines of error messages are hidden by other jekyll output. See the following image. How can I get error messages to be shown?

My jekyll version is 2.4.0, and I'm using octopress over it.

[image: jekyll output]

Answer (score 0):

try a more verbose output with :

```
jekyll build --trace
```

Comment: Some code can be useful to help. Did you have a repository ?

Comment: You mean, the repository my blog is uploaded? I know why this specific ruby error is occurring, but fixing this error is not the point..

Comment: Yes, debugging is sometimes faster when you can reproduce. You screenshot is not enough to spot the problem.